# magento observer not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to detect when a customer changes their password.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sri_log>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Sri_log>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <log>
                <class>Sri_log_Model</class>
            </log>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <log>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>log/Observer</class>
                        <method>detectPwdChange</method>
                    </log>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

my observer.php

```
<?php
class Sri_Log_Model_Observer {

    public function detectPwdChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event              = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer           = $event->getCustomer();
        $postData           = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

        if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$customer->isObjectNew()) {

            if( $postData['change_password'] == 1 && $postData['current_password'] != $postData['password'] ) {
                // Do something
                $file = 'test.txt';
                $message = "test\n\n";
                file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND);

            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

My module is enabled so `app/etc/modules/Sri_log.xml` is ok but the event is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Whatever you do with the customer passwords: **PLEASE BE VERY CAREFUL** with them. Make sure they are not saved to a random textfile that is accessible via browser so that others can read it. Actually: Don't save the customer password somewhere else. Especially not without encryption. That is quite bad.

2.) Please be careful with upper and lower case names. Is the name if your file in `app/etc/modules/Sri_log.xml` really with a lower case "l"?
Is should be renamed to `app/etc/modules/Sri_Log.xml`

3.) Update your module name from `Sri_log` to `Sri_Log` in all config files + directory names + file names.
The path to your module should be `app/code/[community|local]/Sri/Log`.

Also update the following in `config.xml`:

- `<Sri_log>` to `<Sri_Log>`
- `<class>Sri_log_Model</class>` to `<class>Sri_Log_Model</class>`

3.) Update the way you define your observer:

```
   <events>
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <log> <!-- use a better handle here, for example sri_log_detect_password_change -->
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Sri_Log_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>detectPwdChange</method>
                </log>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>
   </events>
```

4.) Last but not least: Your code is hard to read. I've reformatted your code in the question. Please use at least the reformat code function of your IDE before you paste code here. That is also a matter of politeness when you ask for help.